# How do I specify Windows Authentication for an Endpoint in code (not app.config)?

Tags: c#, web-services, binding

I am trying to run a standalone app (i.e. without needing an `app.config`). It uses a webservice and the binding was originally in the app.config as follows:

```
<endpoint address="https://svcmysvc.com/ServiceLibrary/LoginScript.svc/LoginScript.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LoginScriptEndpoint"
                contract="LoginScriptService.ILoginScript" name="LoginScriptEndpoint" />

<binding name="LoginScriptEndpoint">
   <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
   </security>
</binding>
```

The application runs fine with this set in the app.config.

When I try to change this to put it into the code using this:

```
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            binding.AllowCookies = true;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 512000;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 512000;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://svc.mysvc.com/ServiceLibrary/LoginScript.svc/LoginScript.svc");
            LoginScriptClient ls = new LoginScriptClient(binding, address);
            ls.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

I get the following error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'

How do I ensure it uses the local user's windows credentials? (I assume this is what is causing the error.)